# When I run a maven build it is showing the below error

Tags: java, xml, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to maven.

When I run the maven build, it is showing the below error.

> Failed to load web application Context.
>   Here i attached the xml file of context-module.xml

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building digGovRepo Repository AMP project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:set-version (default-set-version) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Removed -SNAPSHOT suffix from version - 1.0
[INFO] Added timestamp to version - 1.0.1807061640
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-test-resource (add-env-test-properties) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\src\main\resources
[INFO] Copying 17 resources to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\target/amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:2.2.0:refresh (refresh-webscripts-repo-and-share) @ digGovRepo ---
[WARNING] Connection failed to localhost:8080, null webapp refresh aborted
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\target\classes
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\com\sun\pdfview\pdfrenderer\0.9.1-patched\pdfrenderer-0.9.1-patched.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (add-module-properties-to-test-classpath) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to alfresco/module/digGovRepo
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (add-module-config-to-test-classpath) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ digGovRepo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\target\test-classes
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\com\sun\pdfview\pdfrenderer\0.9.1-patched\pdfrenderer-0.9.1-patched.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ digGovRepo ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running digGovRepo.digGovRepo.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest
2018-07-06 16:40:36,938  ERROR [test.context.TestContextManager] [main] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3336e6b6] to prepare test instance [digGovRepo.digGovRepo.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest@7c3fdb62]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at com.tradeshift.test.remote.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:alfresco/module-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [alfresco/application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:alfresco/module/*/module-context.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/B5451/.m2/repository/org/alfresco/alfresco-repository/5.1.e/alfresco-repository-5.1.e.jar!/alfresco/module-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:alfresco/module/digGovRepo/context/bootstrap-context.xml]
Offending resource: file [D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\target\test-classes\alfresco\module\digGovRepo\module-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [alfresco/module/digGovRepo/context/bootstrap-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 78; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "xml".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:69)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:95)
    ... 27 more
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.262 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T16:40:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project digGovRepo: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\digGovRepo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Context file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.

-->
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

<beans>

    <!-- This is filtered by Maven at build time, so that module name is single sourced. -->
    <!-- Note. The bootstrap-context.xml file has to be loaded first.
                Otherwise your custom models are not yet loaded when your service beans are instantiated and you
                cannot for example register policies on them. -->
    <import resource="classpath:alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/context/bootstrap-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/context/service-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/context/webscript-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: You have a test and the test fails. You probably want to look into why your test fails. It's hard for us to tell you without having a look at your test and your tested code.

Comment: where is the error? below? it looks like its above. but you said its below? i cant see it below. is it definitely below?

Comment: 1) Don't repeat text in your question (When i run the maven ....) several times.

Comment: Share in your post the content of the file alfresco/module/digGovRepo/module-context.xml. As @duffymo mentioned, it is simply a problem in your xml file.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri So what i need to do in that xml file.

Comment: @karuppasamy it is difficult to say if you do not share its content. Trying to guess, you can remove the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri ...........Pls see the attached below file ( module-context.xml )

Comment: @karuppasamy have you tried to remove the DOCTYPE?

Comment: @karuppasamy you copied in your post the content of a context file that is importing another context file: alfresco/module/digGovRepo/context/bootstrap-context.xml. The problem is in the imported context file and so we cannot really help. Based on the exception, it looks like your xml file is not well formatted: it is saying that the root element is "xml" but instead it is beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the stack trace carefully you'll see that your XML configuration file has a formatting issue:

```
Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [alfresco/module/digGovRepo/context/bootstrap-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 78; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "xml".
```

You're still using XML configuration?  It's time to consider Spring Boot and annotation driven configuration.

What version of Spring are you using?  We're up to 5.x now.

Comment: Am using the spring version ( spring-tool-suite-3.9.4 ) and How to consider the spring boot and annotation driven configuration. @duffymo

Comment: I think Spring Tool Suite is the IDE.  You need to check the version of the Spring JARs its using.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: @duffymo I do not think that spring boot can be used in this case. The context file is loaded by Alfresco that is not based on Spring Boot (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to execute unit tests in the beginning, so try to skip tests by executing `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: True, but I fear that configuration issues will still be present in the deployed app.

Comment: No, this is just a unit test, the error might be related to the test itself